# Libgdx override keyDown using InputMultiplexer in Screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a screen and have created a new multiplexer and set an input processor.

How can I override keyDown on my screen?

```
public class Screen implements Screen, TextInputListener
{
...stuff...
public Screen(Game game)
    {

        multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
        multiplexer.addProcessor(mySystem);
        multiplexer.addProcessor(aStage);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);

    }

...more stuff....

}
```

Thanks

Comment: look in my code i create class that take sprites array and extends class InputAdapter and override keyDown method and update the sprites array

Comment: your code? missing a link?

Comment: :) i can't understand your comment , i was talking on my implementation of some thing like that ,  are you asking to post this code :) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving it:

```
InputProcessor backProcessor = new InputAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean keyDown(int keycode)
            {
                //do stuff
                return false;
            }
        };
multiplexer.addProcessor(backProcessor);
```

Answer (score 3):

To override KeyDown you need to implement InputProcessor.

For example if you want to override the Android Back button and the Backspace button on PC you can use a class like this.

```
public class ScreenInputHandler implements InputProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        if(keycode == Keys.BACK || keycode == Keys.BACKSPACE){       
            ...code here
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Remember add the input handler to your InputMultiplexer.

Comment: This would work I am sure but I wanted to do it without implementing InputProcessor.

Comment: You could always make your "Screen" class implement InputProcessor then add it like this: multiplexer.addProcessor(this);. Or use an inner class like how I have done in my pinch-to-zoom example. But I don't think you can listen for a keydown without ImputProcessor.

Comment: Using an InputAdapter works just fine on my tested code. I am catching the back button and changing screens. I needed access to my game which is why I wanted to keep all of it in the screen so I could change to other screens when the back button was hit.

Comment: If I were to override multiple methods I'd use a class, with a constructor to pass a reference of my game object. Your solution is essentially just an inline shorthand version of my answer.

Comment: If you add that little note I would be happy to accept your answer.